# Как подключить внешнюю библиотеку в Clion

Tags: c++

Как подключить внешнюю библиотеку в Clion?

А именно SFML. Столкнулся с недопониманием. Пишу в терминале (Clion) `brew install sfml`, и проходит момент установки, только все равно не могу использовать в программе, компилятор ругается что такого нет.(использую для сборка CMAKE)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(gamer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(gamer def.cpp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Полагаю, посредством команды `brew install sfml` вы установили данную библиотеку в систему. Для того чтобы использовать ее, Вам необходимо подключить ее к cmake-проекту. Вам следует обратиться к [справочной документации `cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html) и ознакомиться с командами `find_path`, `find_library`, `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS` для того чтобы `cmake` обнаружил установленную библиотеку в системе и `target_link_libraries`, `target_include_directories` - для того чтобы использовать ее в проекте.

Comment: спасибо большое, очень помогли.